# MINIX compiling .c files error

Tags: compilation, mkdir, minix

Im working on minix 3.2.1 . I just put a :
 `printf("hi");`
command in do_mkdir -> open.c ,in many lines , so when i use mkdir 'name' command in shell it prints hi.
I put this printf inside :

> mined /usr/src/servers/vfs/open.c   in do_mkdir function
>   and i compile it with :
>       cd /usr/src/
>       make hdboot
>   and then i reboot. But it just make file, it wont print hi.
>   I tried compile with make install too.. but nothing.
>   I think its problem with compiling. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow fellow Minix fan
If you consider my answer correct you can press the green tick to officially accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `make hdboot` is a command that you can use when you're in the `usr/src/realeasetools` directory. Therefore it's possible that your mistake is simply this. If however that's not the case, then there's a possibility that you're missing some tools. Apart from `make install` try to update your minix. ( I think the command is `make update`, not sure though)